# Reposition geotagged image on mapoeg

Tags: leaflet, gps, open-source-gis, image, geotag

I am building a map in leaflet, rendering a variety of layers on top of the map.
One layer contains geotagged images fetched from a folder (with [Leaflet.Photo](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo)).
Some of the images GPS locations are not accurate enough and I would want to re-position them.
My question is:

- Is there a open source tool that allows repositioning of images on a
  map and edits the exif data accordingly?
- Would this be possible to integrate this into the Leaflet map itself (e.g have the popup contain an 'edit' button that allows write access
  to an images metadata)?